# How to combine multiple IObservable<bool> to form composite bool subscription value

Tags: wpf, system.reactive

I would like to create a kind of Rx based ICommand for WPF. What I would like to do is to be able to control the CanExecute by combining ANY number of IObservable<bool> streams.

The way I would like to work is that I would like to use the latest combined logically ANDed values of all of the predicates, and use that to control the bool  ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter) method implementation. I do not want to wait for all predicates to yield, it should use whatever one of the source predicate streams OnNexts (yields a value).

I have got a bit stuck with trying to work out how to wire it up such that any of the predicates should cause the ICommand.CanExecute to yield a new value.

Forgetting the actually ICommand implementation for a minute (as my question is more about the Rx side of things), can anyone suggest how I can wire up a bunch of predicates ( IObservable<bool>) that yield whenever the underlying things that create their streams change, but will also work in unison to create an overall end bool value that I can subscribe too. The end value would be a logical AND of the current predicate stream values.

I am hoping I do not need to subscribe to all the predicate streams, and am hoping for a cool operator within RX that I may have overlooked.

I know I can Merge streams, but that is not quite the behavior I am after, as that is just the latest value from the input streams that have been merged, I also know that I can CombineLatest, again this is not quite correct, as it will only yield when all the combined streams yield values.

What I want is the streams to be combined so any change will notify a subscriber, but I also want to know what the logical ANDing of the combined predicate IObservable<bool> streams is right now, such that I can drive the ICommand.CanExecute from this overall combined value.

I hope this makes sense.

Here is some skeleton code (I have left some commented out code which shows the thinking behind my Rx Command idea, as it may help to illustrate what I want to get working)

```
public class ViewModel : INPCBase
{
    private string title;
    private bool hasStuff;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        //Initialise some command with 1st predicate, and 
        // initial CanExecute value
        //SomeCommand = new ReactiveCommand(
        //    this.ObserveProperty(x => x.Title)
        //        .Select(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)), false);
        //SomeCommand.AddPredicate(this.ObserveProperty(x => x.HasStuff));
        //SomeCommand.CommandExecutedStream.Subscribe(x =>
        //    {
        //        MessageBox.Show("Command Running");
        //    });

        IObservable<bool> obsPred = this.ObserveProperty(x => x.Title)
          .Select(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
          .StartWith(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Title));
        IObservable<bool> obsPred2 = this.ObserveProperty(x => 
          x.HasStuff).StartWith(this.HasStuff);


        obsPred.Merge(obsPred2).Subscribe(x =>
            {
                //How do I get this to fire whenever obsPred OR 
                //obsPred2 fire OnNext, but also get a combined value (bool) 
                //of the AND of obsPred & obsPred2 (bearing in mind I may 
                //want more than 2 predicates, it should cope with any number of
                //IObservable<bool> predicates
            });
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return this.title;
        }
        set
        {
            RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.title, value, () => Title);
        }
    }


    public bool HasStuff
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hasStuff;
        }
        set
        {
            RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.hasStuff, value, () => HasStuff);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `CombineLatest` operator

```
ISubject<bool> obsPred  = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(false);
ISubject<bool> obsPred2 = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(false);

Observable.CombineLatest(obsPred, obsPred2, (a, b)=>a&&b)
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Dump();

obsPred.OnNext(true);
obsPred2.OnNext(true);
obsPred2.OnNext(true);
obsPred.OnNext(true);

obsPred.OnNext(false);
```

This will output

```
False
True
False
```

The use of `DistinctUntilChanged()` will stop duplicate consecutive values being returned.

Obviously swap out the `BehaviorSubject`s for your property observables.

Comment: Lee I did try CombineLatest/DistinctUntilChanged combo, but doesn't that mean you have to wait for all input streams to yield. To be honest I tried a few things I could be getting confused. I will give it a run through in the morning. I am sure you are right. You were last time. I see you have moved on from Bank Of Canada now too. Liking the new place? As for me I am definitely getting into Rx, its addictive you think a bit here, there then its suddenly in there good. Which is ok in my opinion.

Comment: Aha I think I know why my attempts at using CombineLatest did not work as I expected. From your blog "The CombineLatest extension method allows you to take the most recent value from two sequences, and with a given function transform those into a value for the result sequence. Each input sequence has the last value cached like Replay(1). Once both sequences have produced at least one value, the latest output from each sequence is passed to the resultSelector function every time either sequence produces a value..." so I think I needed to use a StartsWith(false) for initial value

Comment: Still I will try it tomorrow and let you know, and vote you up once I know your answer is correct one (sure it will be ;-) )

Comment: Ok, finally got it, I think it was down to how I was storing the combined stream, and I think I also need to resubscribe. I have posted the working code below, maybe if you want to give it the once over, that would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is how I managed to get this work

```
public interface IReactiveCommand : ICommand
{
    IObservable<object> CommandExecutedStream { get; }
    IObservable<Exception> CommandExeceptionsStream { get; }
    void AddPredicate(IObservable<bool> predicate);
}
```

Then the actual command implementation

```
public class ReactiveCommand : IReactiveCommand, IDisposable
{
    private Subject<object> commandExecutedSubject = new Subject<object>();
    private Subject<Exception> commandExeceptionsSubjectStream = new Subject<Exception>();
    private List<IObservable<bool>> predicates = new List<IObservable<bool>>();
    private IObservable<bool> canExecuteObs;
    private bool canExecuteLatest = true;
    private CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

    public ReactiveCommand(IObservable<bool> initPredicate, bool initialCondition)
    {
        if (initPredicate != null)
        {
            canExecuteObs = initPredicate;
            SetupSubscriptions();
        }
        RaiseCanExecute(initialCondition);
    }


    private void RaiseCanExecute(bool value)
    {
        canExecuteLatest = value;
        this.raiseCanExecuteChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }


    public ReactiveCommand()
    {
         RaiseCanExecute(true);
    }


    private void SetupSubscriptions()
    {

        disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
        disposables.Add(this.canExecuteObs.Subscribe(
            //OnNext
            x =>
            {
                RaiseCanExecute(x);
            },
            //onError
            commandExeceptionsSubjectStream.OnNext
        ));
    }



    public void AddPredicate(IObservable<bool> predicate)
    {
        disposables.Dispose();
        predicates.Add(predicate);
        this.canExecuteObs = this.canExecuteObs.CombineLatest(predicates.Last(), (a, b) => a && b).DistinctUntilChanged();
        SetupSubscriptions();
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecuteLatest;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        commandExecutedSubject.OnNext(parameter);
    }


    public IObservable<object> CommandExecutedStream
    {
        get { return this.commandExecutedSubject.AsObservable(); }
    }

    public IObservable<Exception> CommandExeceptionsStream
    {
        get { return this.commandExeceptionsSubjectStream.AsObservable(); }
    }


    protected virtual void raiseCanExecuteChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.CanExecuteChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       disposables.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Where I am using the following helper

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<TValue> ObserveProperty<T, TValue>(
        this T source,
         Expression<Func<T, TValue>> propertyExpression
    )
        where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        return source.ObserveProperty(propertyExpression, false);
    }

    public static IObservable<TValue> ObserveProperty<T, TValue>(
        this T source,
        Expression<Func<T, TValue>> propertyExpression,
        bool observeInitialValue
    )
        where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body;

        var getter = propertyExpression.Compile();

        var observable = Observable
            .FromEvent<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
                h => new PropertyChangedEventHandler(h),
                h => source.PropertyChanged += h,
                h => source.PropertyChanged -= h)
            .Where(x => x.EventArgs.PropertyName == memberExpression.Member.Name)
            .Select(_ => getter(source));

        if (observeInitialValue)
            return observable.Merge(Observable.Return(getter(source)));

        return observable;
    }


    public static IObservable<string> ObservePropertyChanged<T>(this T source)
       where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        var observable = Observable
            .FromEvent<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
                h => new PropertyChangedEventHandler(h),
                h => source.PropertyChanged += h,
                h => source.PropertyChanged -= h)
            .Select(x => x.EventArgs.PropertyName);

        return observable;
    }
}
```

And here is an example of how to wire it up

Here is an example ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel : INPCBase
{
    private string title;
    private bool hasStuff;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        IObservable<bool> initPredicate = this.ObserveProperty(x => x.Title).Select(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).StartWith(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Title));
        IObservable<bool> predicate = this.ObserveProperty(x => x.HasStuff).StartWith(this.HasStuff);
        SomeCommand = new ReactiveCommand(initPredicate, false);
        SomeCommand.AddPredicate(predicate);
        SomeCommand.CommandExecutedStream.Subscribe(x =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Command Running");
            });
    }

    public ReactiveCommand SomeCommand { get; set; }



    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return this.title;
        }
        set
        {
            RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.title, value, () => Title);
        }
    }


    public bool HasStuff
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hasStuff;
        }
        set
        {
            RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.hasStuff, value, () => HasStuff);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is an example View

```
<Window x:Class="RxCommand.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding HasStuff, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="10"></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="150" Margin="10"></TextBox>
            <Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" Width="150" Margin="10"></Button>


        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I assume you have pulled most of that code from pre existing snippets/libraries! Otherwise that is a heap of code, to just do what ICommand does quite simply. ;-)

Comment: I would further add that to swap the `StartWith` around for DRY :  `this.ObserveProperty(x => x.Title).StartWith(this.Title).Select(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));`

Comment: Lee I can totally see what you mean by the DRY comment. Ill amend that. As for the heap of code comment, not sure I follow that one. I think I need most of that stuff. What do you think could be removed from it. Just curious to know. Most of its helper stuff for observing properties, perhaps you mean that?

Comment: Yeah the helper stuff. ReactiveCommand is probably a reimplementation of the one from ReactiveUI and the other stuff looks like it is from Rxx.

Comment: Helper stuff is cobbled together from here there everywhere (mainly Keith woods blog) , reactive UI does have s reactive command but I wanted to be able to add predicates which it doesn't allow, so that's what this SO was all about, still all good now thanks again

Comment: Yeah Keith is an awesome programmer. For sure